# Change source of image

Tags: jquery, image

I want to use an image called `#MapButtonImage` as a 'button' so when somebody clicks on it, a div is shown and the source of the `#MapButtonImage` changes.
I have made it so that it shows the div as follows:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $("img#MapButtonImage").click(function(){
  $("div.MapMain").toggleClass('MapMainShow');
  });
});
```

When I click the button at the moment, it changes the class of the map div to display:block, then the second click goes back to the default of display:none.

But I can't seem to make it change the source of the image using jQuery. I followed a guide using a toggle of two functions with the source as the two images I want, but it only works on an earlier version of jQuery and not the latest.

The image #MapButtonImage has original source "ShowMapButton.jpg" and I want to change it to "HideMapButton.jpg" when it is clicked on, then back to "ShowMapButton.jpg" when clicked again.

The aim is to have it as a toggle to show a Map div below it and the image reflects the action that the button will then take (Show or Hide).

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am quite new to this and can't understand why it doesn't work in the latest version but does in a previous.

Comment: Did you try `$('#MapButtonImage').attr('src','newurl');`

Comment: Why not use a `button` element and change the background url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $("img#MapButtonImage").click(function(){
  $("div.MapMain").toggleClass('MapMainShow');

  if($("div.MapMain").hasClass('MapMainShow')) {
      $(this).attr('src', 'HideMapButton.jpg');
  } else {
      $(this).attr('src', 'ShowMapButton.jpg');
  }
  });
});
```

Comment: [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) is more appropriate than `.prop()` in this case.

Comment: That is perfect, thanks so much! I only have one issue with my code now and that is that this jquery part does not function in IE8, is there an obvious answer as to why this would be without seeing the whole code? It works fine in Chome and Firefox latest versions. Thanks again for your help.